# Shell script to merge files with same names

Tags: shell-script, files, pdf

I have a directory of files such as:

```
file.1111111_1.pdf
file.1111111_2.pdf
file.2222222_1.pdf
file.2222222_2.pdf
…
file.1234567_1.pdf
file.1234567_2.pdf
…
file.aaaaaaa_1.pdf
file.aaaaaaa_2.pdf
…
file.abcdefg_1.pdf
file.abcdefg_2.pdf
```

How can I merge the first 7digit same file name to new file in same directory or subdirectory, It should end up like this:

```
file.1111111.pdf
file.2222222.pdf
…
file.1234567.pdf
…
file.aaaaaaa.pdf
…
file.abcdefg.pdf
```

Comment: Is there always a `_1` file and a `_2` file? Always a `_1` file and possibly a `_2`, a `_3`, a `_4`, etc.?

Answer (score 3):

There are many tools to merge pdf files, one of them is `pdfunite`. Simple one-liner to do what you need with this tool looks like this:

```
for file in file.*_*.pdf; do [[ -e ${file%_*}.pdf ]] && \
    continue || pdfunite ${file%_*}_*.pdf ${file%_*}.pdf; done
```

I use here [parameter expansion mechanism](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) `${file%_*}` to remove suffix pattern `_*` from matched file name and create `${file%_*}.pdf` as the output file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick example using the 'convert' command:

```
$ ls
files.txt  TEST.pdf
```

`TEST.pdf` is an Adobe PDF I got from [here](http://mensenhandel.nl/files/pdftest2.pdf). It is just an example I used to populate the rest of your file names.

The names of your files are in `files.txt`

```
$ cat files.txt 
file.1111111_1.pdf file.1111111_2.pdf file.2222222_1.pdf file.2222222_2.pdf file.1234567_1.pdf file.1234567_2.pdf file.aaaaaaa_1.pdf file.aaaaaaa_2.pdf file.abcdefg_1.pdf file.abcdefg_2.pdf
```

Using this file I generate my test data:

```
$ for i in $(<files.txt); do cp TEST.pdf $i; done

$ ls
file.1111111_1.pdf  file.1234567_1.pdf  file.2222222_1.pdf  file.aaaaaaa_1.pdf  file.abcdefg_1.pdf  files.txt
file.1111111_2.pdf  file.1234567_2.pdf  file.2222222_2.pdf  file.aaaaaaa_2.pdf  file.abcdefg_2.pdf  TEST.pdf
```

Now we can loop over all of the files that match your name structure. Then place them into an appropriate sub-directory.  Then we use the 'convert' command to merge those PDFs into a single file.

```
$ for pdf in $(ls *.*_*.pdf); do base=$(echo $pdf | cut -d_ -f1) ; \
    [[ -d $base ]] || mkdir $base ; mv $pdf $base/ ; \
    convert $base/*_*.pdf $base/$base.pdf ; done

$ ls
file.1111111  file.1234567  file.2222222  file.aaaaaaa  file.abcdefg  files.txt  TEST.pdf

$ ls file.1111111/ 
file.1111111_1.pdf  file.1111111_2.pdf  file.1111111.pdf
```

`file.11111111.pdf` in the sub-directory is your merged file.